# Return type depending on another generic type of function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function, which accepts type of data it's going to return, and I want to change return type depending on another type passed in function

```
export async function http<T>(request: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit): Promise<HttpResponse<T>> {
    const response: HttpResponse<T> = await fetch(
        request, init
    );

    try {
        response.parsedBody = await response.json();
        response.parsedSuccessfully = true;
    } catch (ex) {
        response.parsedSuccessfully = false;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Usual consumer looks like this:

```
http<string>(`http://localhost/...`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {...}
}).then((data) => {
    if (data.ok && ...) {
        //do something
    }
})
```

But I want to change the function so it can return .text(), .json(), .blob(), which types are `string`, `T` and `Blob` respectively, so I tried the following:

```
export async function http<T>(request: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit, data: 'text' | 'json' | 'blob' = 'json'): Promise<HttpResponse<T>> {
    const response: HttpResponse<T> = await fetch(
        request, init
    );

    try {
        if (data === 'text') {
            response.parsedBody = await response.text()
        }
        response.parsedBody = await response.json();
        response.parsedSuccessfully = true;
    } catch (ex) {
        response.parsedSuccessfully = false;
    }

    return response;
}
```

but it says, that Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T | undefined'

and this:

```
export async function http<T, V extends string = 'text' | 'json' | 'blob'>(request: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit, bodyType: V = 'json'): Promise<HttpResponse<T>> {
    const response: HttpResponse<T> = await fetch(
        request, init
    );

    try {
        if (bodyType === 'text') {
            response.parsedBody = await response.text()
        }
        response.parsedBody = await response.json();
        response.parsedSuccessfully = true;
    } catch (ex) {
        response.parsedSuccessfully = false;
    }

    return response;
}
```

but it is also wrong

`export async function http<T>(request: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit, data: 'text' | 'json' | 'blob' = 'json'): Promise<HttpResponse<T | string | Blob>>`

is also wrong, how do I do it right? So I pass `http<string, 'text'>(...)` and it returns me `response.text()` in parsedBody?

Comment: Seems a bit of an overkill to define one function that will just call `fetch` and handle the error. When you still need to handle the error further later. Only instead of having to catch the rejection from `.json()`, you now need to do `if (data.parsingSuccessful)` and do something about it. I'd just define an error handler for that situation and re-use it, no need to "attempt to parse -> record whether it's successful -> check if it's successful -> handle failure" when you can just "attempt to parse -> handle failure"

Comment: @VLAZ the function was written to type the return value, which comes from fetch as it done here (https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/), so now I just want to return not only json, but also a text and blob from response

Comment: Point is to not just write a framework to handle this one function call. Instead define your error handler, then call `fetch()` and only use the error handler. Then you can use `.json()` or `.text()` or anything else you need without having to build up the framework that *only calls `fetch()` for you*.

Comment: There is not reason to discuss why I wrote the function, because, again, I did is to type data, which I get from `fetch()`, I do not really care about errors. As you can see in consumer example, I will know, that `data` will be a `string`. And the only thing I want to do now is make that function return not only `.json()`, but also a `.text()`, which type differs from `T`